# _this.subscribe is not a function in angular 2 async Validation

Tags: validation, asynchronous, angular

I'm try to make a async validations in angular 2 but get `this.subscribe is not a function`.

My FormGroup is:

```
const form = new FormGroup({
  example: new FormControl('example', [Validators.required], [CustomValidators.example]),
  last: new FormControl('Drew'),
});
```

My custom async validation

```
....

example (value : number) : AsyncValidatorFn {
  return (control: AbstractControl): Observable< {[key:string]: boolean} > => {
    return this.restService.exampleService(value)  
};
```

the exampleService return a object in the form `{match: true}`

```
exampleService (value : any) {
  return this._http.get(AppSettings.API_ENDPOINT + "company/findByNit/" + value )
         .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The validations should be grouped in just one array. Try this

```
const form = new FormGroup({
  example: new FormControl('example', [Validators.required, CustomValidators.example]),
  last: new FormControl('Drew'),
});
```